# Showing UIView with bouncy animation

Tags: ios, ios7, uianimation

I want to create a bouncy animation like in the Skitch application - when i press a button, a subview (simple view with several buttons) will appear from the side and will bounce a bit until it stops.

I can't find any standard animation that does that, so how i can implement this animation?

Comment: there is no 'standard' animation for it because that is so essential to make such animation manually in a minute.

Comment: you use this sight for implement this animation:
"http://code4app.net/ios/Bounce-Animation/505fcc1a6803fabb63000000"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this :

```
// Hide your view by setting its position to outside of the bounds of the screen

// Whenever you want, call this :
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
      initialSpringVelocity:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{

                     // Set your final view position here

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                 }];
```

This method is the same as the usual `animateWithDuration:` but it introduces a spring animation.

Answer (score 2):

Use UIView method:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                      delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay 
     usingSpringWithDamping:(CGFloat)dampingRatio 
      initialSpringVelocity:(CGFloat)velocity 
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options 
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations 
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

This will do what you want

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIView method, If you want bouncing effect. Then you need to nested the animation process and give the frame as needed for that view. Here's the example:

```
CGRect frameOnStart = CGRectMake(200,200 ,60 ,60); //On start show small view

CGRect frameOnAnimate = CGRectMake(80,80 ,150 , 150); //while animate show large view

CGRect frameAfterAnimate = CGRectMake(100,100,120 ,120);  //after animate large take it back to original frame. SO it loos like bouncing animation

// Whenever you want, call this :
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
      initialSpringVelocity:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{

                     // Set your on Animate position here
                     view.frame = frameOnAnimate;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                           delay:0
                          usingSpringWithDamping:0.5
                           initialSpringVelocity:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                      animations:^{

                                          // Set your final view position here
                                          view.frame = frameAfterAnimate;
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {


                                      }]

                 }];
```

Thanks.